# Shell Script Eliminate full path while creating zip

Tags: bash

I have directory path /root/Archive/EKS/data - Under this data folder I have some text file, my goal is need take entire data directory and keep the zipped file into same place (/root/Archive/EKS/data.

But the below is script is working as we expected but when I'm doing unzipping the folder path start from /root/Archive/EKS/data, its repeating but I don't want to make zip based on full path instead it needs to create zip file based on data directory only.

```
└─# tree root/
root/
└── Archive
    └── EKS
        └── validate-file
3 directories, 0 files
```

```
startdir=(
"/root/Archive/EKS/data"
)

for dir in "${startdir[@]}" ; do
    for sub_dir in "$dir"/*/ ; do
        zip "${sub_dir%/}".zip "$sub_dir"
    done
done
```

can you please guide me where I'm missing it.

Comment: I think you have to `cd` to the parent directory and run `zip` there instead of providing absolute paths to `zip`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    startdir="/root/Archive/EKS/data"
    
    cd "$startdir" || exit
    
    for sub_dir in */ ; do
        zip -r "${sub_dir%/}.zip" "$sub_dir"
    done
```

cd **$startdir** command changes the working directory to /root/Archive/EKS/data.

Then we iterate through each subdirectory (*/) within the **data** directory and create the zip file.

hope it helps.

Comment: I think this will not work if when i pass multiple directory  startdir="/root/Archive/EKS/data" "/root/Archive/EKS/data1"

Comment: Hi@Meehan can u pls help me

Comment: Wrap this answer into another loop on the multiple directory values.  You already do that in your initial code.